# Does GQLAlchemy support migrations equivalent to DjangoORM or Alembic?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm learning how to do whings with GQLAlchemy. And I wonder does GQLAlchemy support migrations equivalent to DjangoORM or Alembic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for such equivalents. In the Memgraph GitHub repo you can find an open issue for this feature https://github.com/memgraph/gqlalchemy/issues/17.